# What does おとくな　けいじばん mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, sentence

I was playing ポケットモンスターファイアーレッド (Pokémon fire red) when I noticed that this appears when I start reading most of the signs:

[image: おとくな けいじばん]

I've searched for it in a couple of sites, and it looks like けいじばん is bulletin board, but I didn't find what おとくな means, nor what the sentence is saying.

Comment: I think if you know *na*-adjectives and how to use a dictionary, you'll be able to answer this question yourself...

Comment: [おとくなけいじばん - ポケモンWiki](https://wiki.ポケモン.com/wiki/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%91%E3%81%84%E3%81%98%E3%81%B0%E3%82%93)

Comment: Hint: おとく is the adjective な is what connects it to the next word. You should be only looking for the adjective, without the "connector"

Comment: Further hint: お　とく　 the お just makes the word more polite. So look up とく and けいじばん　and you've got your answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's the na-adjective 得【とく】 with a polite prefix お. As a na-adjective it means "profitable", and お works in various ways, but here you can think of it "for you". So お得な is as a whole like "(that) profits you".

> [image]
>   [jisho.org: 得](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BE%97)

Thus お得【とく】(な) is a very common fixed phrase in the real life. The definition below reflects very well what settings they use it frequently in.

> [image: jisho.org]
>   [jisho.org: お得](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%8A%E5%BE%97)

If you don't know how to use a dictionary or what a na-adjective is, please read some beginner material.

Comment: The definition shown in the image doesn't seem to answer this question. ("an economical board"?) Although it's a community wiki, I'm not sure if it's correct to change it drastically...

Comment: @broccoliforest drasticに変えるか補足を追記していただければ助かります…w

Comment: やってみます…………………………